# Apache Ranger cannot connect to Hive through spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-ranger

We have a working installation of Apache Ranger 1.0.0. We did hive service setup and defined policies on hive tables to restrict access. This hive service is using a jbdc connection string with port 10000 (default port). It is working fine.

We tried to setup ranger for spark sql. using the link

https://www.mail-archive.com/user@ranger.incubator.apache.org/msg00799.html

But when i tried to click on "Test connection" button in the Ranger UI, it throws me below error.

[image: Ranger UI connection failed message for spark sql port]

When i click on the "show more" button, it gives this error

```
org.apache.ranger.plugin.client.HadoopException: Unable to connect to Hive Thrift Server instance.. 
Unable to connect to Hive Thrift Server instance.. 
Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://hostnameremoved:10015/default;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/home/ec2-user/sslfile.jks;trustStorePassword=abcd: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://hostnameremoved:10015/default;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/home/ec2-user/sslfile.jks;trustStorePassword=abcd: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{set:hiveconf:hive.server2.thrift.resultset.default.fetch.size=1000, use:database=default}). 
Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://hostnameremoved:10015/default;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/home/ec2-user/sslfile.jks;trustStorePassword=abcd: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{set:hiveconf:hive.server2.thrift.resultset.default.fetch.size=1000, use:database=default}). 
Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{set:hiveconf:hive.server2.thrift.resultset.default.fetch.size=1000, use:database=default}).
```

we are using Hive version - apache-hive-2.3.2.5.

However, Spark sql works fine when connecting through spark_home/bin/beeline, or through any sql clients with same jdbc connection string that we used in ranger service.

Any pointers will be greatly helpful.